# Replacing with a raw string literal?

Tags: python

If I have a string

```
s = 'this is a \n tennis ball'
```

and if perform in python:

```
s.replace("\n", "nice")
```

the output is:

```
"this is a nice tennis ball"
```

On the other hand if I perform in python

```
s.replace(r"\n","nice"),
```

the output is

```
"this is a \n tennis ball"
```

What is the difference between using simple plain string and using `r` raw string and what is the reason for these different outputs.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `str.replace()`. You should really look at the different values `'\n'` and `r'\n'` produce.

Answer (score 0):

An 'r' string literal makes the `'\'` character represent an actual `'\'` character instead of a special character and it behaves as a raw string.

In the string `s = 'this is a \n tennis ball'`, if you add an 'r', so its `s = r'this is a \n tennis ball'` it will recognize the '\' sign as a regular raw '\' sign and recognize it when you use the `r'\'` while using `s.replace()`

I might not have been very clear in my explanation, I suggest reading the answer to [What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: The behaviour follows directly from an understanding of what raw string literals are: no replacement occurs, because *the string described by the raw string literal is not actually a substring of the larger text*. On this basis, I have closed the question as a duplicate.